# sql sum two columns and add up both

Tags: php, select, mysqli, count, sum

I have a database with multiple scores of tabletennis matches.
To make a ranking I need to count multiple columns.

I want to add up the unique rounds to know how often people have participated. And I also want to add up all the winning games. Sometimes we play a "super round" (SR) where the winning games are doubled. SR is set to 1 by default.

To know the total score, I want to add up both outcomes (participation & total_games).

What I have now:

```
$sql_user = $conn->query("
SELECT user_id, count(distinct round) as participation, 
sum(IFNULL(GAMES_WIN,0) * SR) AS total_games 
FROM tt_game group by user_id ORDER BY user_id ASC");
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
$sql_user = $conn->query("
SELECT user_id, count(distinct round) as participation, 
sum(IFNULL(GAMES_WIN,0) * SR) AS total_games 
sum(participation + total_games) AS total_score
FROM tt_game group by user_id ORDER BY total_score DESC");
```

And how do I echo these outcomes?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot reference the alias names defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `SELECT` clause itself.

You can either repeat the expressions:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  count(distinct round) as participation, 
  sum(IFNULL(GAMES_WIN,0) * SR) AS total_games, 
  count(distinct round) + sum(IFNULL(GAMES_WIN,0) * SR) AS total_score
FROM tt_game 
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY total_score DESC;
```

Or use a subquery:

```
SELECT user_id, participation, total_games, participation + total_game AS total_score
FROM
(
  SELECT
    user_id,
    count(distinct round) as participation, 
    sum(IFNULL(GAMES_WIN,0) * SR) AS total_games
  FROM tt_game 
  GROUP BY user_id
) aggregated
ORDER BY total_score DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about another select?

I think you need another select, where you calculate total_score.

Try something like this:

```
$sql_user = $conn->query("
SELECT t.user_id, t.participation, t.total_games, (participation + total_games) AS total_score
FROM (SELECT user_id, count(distinct round) as participation, sum(IFNULL(GAMES_WIN, 0) * SR) AS total_games
      FROM tt_game
      group by user_id
      ORDER BY total_score DESC) AS t
");
```